# Webforms and Template Inheritance parameters

Tags: c#, templates, sharepoint, webforms

Hi I'm learning a bit of webforms for a sharepoint 2010 module I'm helping with.
I've got a background with razor and enjoy inheriting templates and then using parameters set in the controller to influence the layout.

So in my system I've got a similar setup.

Index.aspx with

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="CESA19Template.Layouts.CESA19Template.Index" MasterPageFile="ValidationTemplate.master" %>
```

ValidationTemplate.master with

```
<%@ Master Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="../Template/Template.master"  AutoEventWireup="true"  %>
```

and the master with

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>
```

I would like to add a parameter into the .cs behind ValidationTemplate (ValidationTemplate.master.cs) and then use that in the template as well as have my Index.aspx page change the parameter.

I've tried loads of CodeBehind and all sorts can someone help me, or isn't this possible and needs another way? (maybe a include)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this - basically you need to get the public key from the file behind it and then this works.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="../Template/Template.master"  AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CESA19Template.Layouts.CESA19Template.ValidationTemplate,CESA19Template,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=68cf004eb48f0fd4"
```

I guess this is probably sharepoint 2010 being a bit daft.